# How to create clickable imageButton?

Tags: android

I am creating a custom button to use in imageButton. I want to know will the button have a click effect when it is clicked by a user? If not what do i need to do to make it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you want the click effect on the imagebutton... if so try [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) and use selector for your purpose...